# In Python, how can I transform a dictionary into a df column, where the keys match the df.index values?

Tags: python, numpy, dictionary, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe and a dictionary, the keys of the dict are the same as the index value of the dataframe, like these:

```
A = pd.DataFrame([[1, 5, 2], [2, 4, 4], [3, 3, 1], [4, 2, 2], [5, 1, 4]],
                 columns=['A', 'B', 'C'], index=["1a", "2a", "3a", "4a", "5a"])

B = {'1a': 0.5, '2a': 0.75, '3a': 0.625, '4a': 0.55, '5a': 1}
```

How can I convert the values of the dictionary into values of a column in the dataframe, matching their respective key - index value. So the output would be like this:

```
    A  B  C  D
1a  1  5  2  0.5
2a  2  4  4  0.75
3a  3  3  1  0.625
4a  4  2  2  0.55
5a  5  1  4  1
```

The new column 'D' has all the values from the dictionary 'B' and each index value in the dataframe matches it correspondent key value in the dict.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can wrap the `dict` with `pandas.Series` and then simply create it as a column:

```
In [633]: A['D'] = pd.Series(B)

In [634]: A
Out[634]: 
    A  B  C      D
1a  1  5  2  0.500
2a  2  4  4  0.750
3a  3  3  1  0.625
4a  4  2  2  0.550
5a  5  1  4  1.000
```